# How should I insert permanent data using SQLite database in android studio?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I want to make a travel guide app using android studio. I want to insert some data about travel destinations such as: their name, location, and etc.  I think that data is permanent, not a dynamic one. How should I put the code for inserting that data? Do I have to make one class that contain the code for inserting all the data to SQLite database?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called **propulate a database**.

The current approach from the android team is to use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) to handle database actions. You can create a sqlite database locally, insert some data and add it to your andorid project's `assets` folder (you might need to create it first). Then at the first start of your app, you can copy the content to the database of your app by using Room's `createFromAsset()` method.

> To prepopulate a Room database from a prepackaged database file that is located anywhere in your app's assets/ directory, call the createFromAsset() method from your RoomDatabase.Builder object before calling build():

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
    .createFromAsset("database/myapp.db")
    .build();
```

> The createFromAsset() method accepts a string argument that contains a relative path from the assets/ directory to the prepackaged database file. (Source: [Prepopulate your Room database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate))

Check out the guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate).

Comment: where should I insert some data and add it my project's assets? Should I make a class that contain the code to insert data to SQLite database?

Comment: Either that or if it's a lot of data, create a local sqlite database on your computer with something like the [sqlite cli](https://sqlite.org/cli.html).